# jquery variable id selector with span tag

Tags: jquery, selector

I'm  trying to select a variable id span tag with jquery but not succeeding. So far, I could do with static id like this:

```
$('#mytextId span').html(mytext);
```

and with the variable is ok as well

```
$("#" + myvariableid).html(mytext);
```

I need to insert the span tag and this does not work:

```
$('"#" + myvariableid  span').html ();
```

what's the right syntax for it ?

Comment: `$("#" + myvariableid + " span").html();`

Comment: Why do you have space after `html`? Shouldn't it be `html();` ?

Comment: $('#'+myvariableid+' span').html('abcd') will work, this does abcd  to be inserted in span!!!!!!

Comment: @dingo_d copied from question :)

Comment: did it work pardeep.. Ya my answer says the same

Answer (score 1):

This line means: Add text `span text` to the `<span>` tag with id `mytextId`:

```
$('span#mytextId').text('span text');
```

Add text to `<span>` tag with class `mytextClass`:

```
$('span.mytextClass').text('span text');
```

Add text to all `<span>` tags:

```
$('span').text('span text');
```

Specific id:

```
var id = 'myId';
$('#' + id).text('my text');
```

`<div>` tag contains `<span>` tag:

```
<div class="myDiv">
   <span class="mySpan"></span>
<div>

$('.myDiv > .mySpan').text('span text');
```

Hope this will help you!